# guild.channels.cache.array() returns an empty array. same with client.channels.cache.array()

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This code returns an empty array - `[]` why? The guild has got lots of channels.

```js
'use strict'

import { Client } from 'discord.js'

const bot = new Client

bot.login('token')

bot.guilds.fetch('826581310151196712').then(server => {
  console.log(server.channels.cache.array())
})
```

Comment: I think you also need to access the cache of guilds don't you? So like this: bot.guilds.cache.fetch
Also in the docs they say you should use .get(id) and not fetch. But I think both works

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop over the array or spread it.

```js
bot.guilds.fetch('826581310151196712')
  .then({ channels : { cache : { array } } } => {
    for (const channel of array()) {
      console.log(channel.id);
    }
  })
```

Maybe you could try: `[...array()]`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly do it that way. The best way is to filter for the channel types you want to display and then map it.

```
  const T = client.guilds.cache.get(args[0]);
    if (!T) return;
      console.log(T.channels.cache.filter(C=> C.type === 'text' || C.type === 'voice').map(Chan => Chan.name));
```

For a brand new server this will output:

> [ 'general', 'General' ]